# Synchronize USB hard drive between Mac and PC

Tags: software-recommendation, data-synchronization, hard-drive

I have a large (750GB) FAT32 formatted USB hard drive and two computers - a MacBook and a PC - and I want to keep synched and duplicate versions of my work folders (images, word documents, videos etc) on each device: the hard drive, Mac and PC.

To achieve this I imagine a folder synchronization software running on both Mac and PC (ideally the same software) which would sync selected folders between the computer and hard drive.

Does anyone know of such a piece of software?

Many thanks!

Comment: 750MB, really? Or 750GB, which would prevent any sensibly priced cloud solution...

Comment: ha ha, good point. He must had meant 750GB - but that doesn't mean it is all used. I've found 2-3GB plenty of room for my 'mission critical' work files. If you set it up sensibly and don't sync apps, movies, etc. You can get 100GB of space from Google for $5/month - but if you really use that much space routinely the syncing will chew up a lot of your internet bandwidth.

Comment: 750GB, yes. My bad. And I do use Dropbox for all word documents and PDFs etc. However, I do need to keep in sync all my photos (about 150GB) which are often 30MB per file. It gets a bit much for clouds...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's new and it's call [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html), just came out of Alpha. It uses a 32 character code you create to create folder based sharepoints...on any computer on your network, without futzing with Preferences. Bittorent does all the work, and you essentially can create your own cloud at will, with any internal or external hdd's.

Comment: Could you add a link to the website of the tool please?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could find folder sync software for both platforms and do this manually, but really those solutions are starting to wither in favor of cloud based sync solutions.

Does what you're looking for, just over the internet (with a persistent cache on your local machine in case you're not online). I've used dropbox to do this exact task for a couple years now, and couldn't imaging going back to a more manual/client based solution.

There are numerous services that offer this, with more storage than you need (5GB is typical). The most well known are DropBox, Google Drive, Box.net and SugarSync. I would highly recommend you look at these before investing in client software to do this.

edit: I just happened to run into a New York Times article that discussed this very issue. See [A User’s Guide to Finding Storage Space in the Cloud](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/17/technology/personaltech/a-computer-users-guide-to-cloud-storage.html?smid=pl-share)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at using [FreeFileSync](http://freefilesync.sourceforge.net) to sync between the PC and the hard drive and then using [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/index.html) to sync between the Mac and the hard drive.

However, a better solution would be to create a "cloud" with your own external drive.  If you have a spare machine lying around that you could convert to a Linux server, you could create your own cloud server for free using [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) or [Tonido](http://www.tonido.com), both of which offer sync clients for Mac and PC.  If you don't have a spare machine or want a simpler way to do this, you can buy a [PogoPlug](http://pogoplug.com) or [TonidoPlug](http://www.tonidoplug.com) which essentially turn any USB drive into a NAS (Network Attached Storage).  PogoPlug offers an easier to use interface, but TonidoPlug is more extensible.  Both of these offer sync applications as well.